# Measuring coredump time

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

When a process crashes I want to measure how long it takes to dumpcore. My understanding is its a kernel function that does the dumpcore. Any kernel experts here can point to the right places where I can add hooks to measure the coredump time ? This is in a 64 bit kernel, version 2.6.3*

Comment: What would you do with that information?

Comment: I think a process can't be resarted till core dump completes for the crashed instance. This system provides critical functionality. So at least I have to know how long my process restart can take.

Comment: @Mat:  Someone working on the coredump facility would use it to profile and optimize the code.  Someone evaluating/maintaining an application which frequently coredumps would be interested for operational reasons.  Heck, idle curiosity is plenty of justification IMHO.

Comment: What do you mean by "restarting a core-dumping process"? You can only start processes (with `fork` syscall) and execute programs (with `execve` syscall). I don't think that the kernel delays the `execve` of a binary which has a process core-dumping... Old supercomputers from the 1990s have been rumored to have core dumps taking dozens of minutes...

Comment: When a process crashes does the kernel generate the SIGCHLD while writing core is in progress or after finishing coredump ? I was assuming its the latter. In my case, the crashing process has to be restarted by the parent that is waiting for SIGCHLD or by upstart (which should rely on SIGCHLD too)

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need to modify the kernel.  The Linux kernel inotify facility can be used to let you know when a core file is created and you can use the file's modification time to tell you when the core dump finished.

But if you have access to the source code for the process, you can have it

1. catch the signal that would have caused a coredump
2. write a timestamp somewhere
3. reset the signal handler back to the default
4. resend the signal to itself, which will cause a coredump this time.

The coredump interval is the last modification time of the core file, minus the timestamp the process wrote earlier.

Comment: that might work. ls shows the modification time only in the precision of HH:MM. But probably its stored in higher resolution ? I can check it out using stat()